# Issue while using url tag

Tags: python, html

I'm using a Django tag to call an `url` to call an `html` page where I've created a button. But when I define my url in the `urls.py` and I restarted the server, I have an `internal server error`. Here's the code from the `urls.py`

```
url(r'^layer_quarantine/', TemplateView.as_wiew(template_name='layer_quarantine.html'), name='layer_quarantine'),
```

And here it's how I call it in my over `html` file.

```
<div class="page-header">
    {% user_can_add_resource_base as add_tag %}
    {% if add_tag %}
        <a href="{% url "layer_upload" %}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">{% trans "Upload Layers" %}</a>
        <a style="margin-right:30px" href="{% url "layer_quarantine" %} class="btn btn-warning pull-right"></a>
    {% endif %}
    <h2 class="page-title">{% trans "Explore Layers" %}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It is `view`, not `wiew`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your urls:

```
url(r'^layer_quarantine/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='layer_quarantine.html'), name='layer_quarantine'),
```